# Setting .SFUI-* fonts in Xamarin appears to correctly use the font extension to convert but still an warning error occurs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code is setting to use the System font like this:

```
Current.Resources["Default-Light"] = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ?
                                     ".SFUI-Light" :
                                     "Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto-Light";
Current.Resources["Default-Medium"] = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ?
                                     ".SFUI-Medium" :
                                     "Roboto-Medium.ttf#Roboto-Medium";
Current.Resources["Default-Light"] = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ?
                                     ".SFUI-Light" :
                                     "Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto-Light";
Current.Resources["Default-Bold"] = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ?
                                     ".SFUI-Bold" :
                                     "Roboto-Bold.ttf#Roboto-Bold";
```

I understand that there's a concern when people use .SFUI-*.

However I also see this extension in the current XF code:

```
 if (family.StartsWith(".SFUI", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var fontWeight = family.Split('-').LastOrDefault();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fontWeight) && System.Enum.TryParse<UIFontWeight>(fontWeight, true, out var uIFontWeight))
                    {
                        result = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(size, uIFontWeight);
                        return result;
                    }

                    result = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(size, UIFontWeight.Regular);
                    return result;
                }
                if(result == null)
                    result = UIFont.FromName(family, size);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
```

here:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/main/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Extensions/FontExtensions.cs

So, why does this message appear?

> 2020-07-03 00:30:19.911 J.iOS[5130:1664473] CoreText note: Client
> requested name ".SFUI-Bold", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than
> the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper
> APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[UIFont
> systemFontOfSize:].

Should the XF iOS extension not have already done the conversion and if that's the case why is the message appearing in the logs?

Bonus question: how can I stop this happening? Can I make my own font extension for this that gets called first.

For reference:

Here is where I am using the fonts:

```
        if(newValue != null && (bool)newValue)
        {
            DeckGridTemplate deckGridTemplate = bindable as DeckGridTemplate;
            deckGridTemplate.TL.FontFamily = (string)Application.Current.Resources["Default-Medium"];
        }
        else
        {
            DeckGridTemplate deckGridTemplate = bindable as DeckGridTemplate;
            deckGridTemplate.TL.FontFamily = (string)Application.Current.Resources["Default-Regular"];
        }
```

Comment: Which version of Xamarin.Forms are you using?

Comment: Hi Mihail,  I am using 4.7.0.968

Comment: It seems like the .SFUI-* font descriptions I have been adding ( it's for a screen that I want to look very much like the iOS settings pages ) do work.  But I am confused as to why this message is appearing.

Comment: So the fonts are working, but you're getting this warning. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct. I checked out the extension (link in the question).  I am wondering if it's some code that comes earlier in the extension before it is changed to use the UIFont.SystemFontOfSize

Comment: This sounds like a warning that Apple is issuing. There is a similar comment on a GitHub issue about this topic: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8035#issuecomment-596617782 As you can see, user esenciadev is having the same question. I have tagged him to see if there's any movement on the subject and will reply back here when any. For now, I don't think that this should be an issue.

Comment: @MihailDuchev - Do you think there's any way to write my own custom code that would intercept this: deckGridTemplate.TL.FontFamily = (string)Application.Current.Resources["Default-Medium"]; and change it to do something different if it was iOS.  For example set it to a system font with a medium weight? If you could help out with an answer for that then I could accept that as an answer while waiting to hear back from Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a warning that Apple is issuing just to "scary you". There is a similar comment on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8035#issuecomment-596617782) about this topic. As you can see, user *esenciadev* is having the same question. I have tagged him to see if there's any movement on the subject and will reply back here when any. For now, I don't think that this should be an issue, since you are displaying the desired font.

As for the custom code to intersept this behaviour. Unfortunately, you can't write such middleware, since this is deep into Xamarin. You have chosen to not import any fonts and just use the system ones. You can only set the in your xaml/cs and the platform will do the rest - checks, warnings, etc.

Comment: How about a custom label renderer?  I'll open up a question with bounty to see if you or others want to look into it a bit more.  Thanks for your guidance on this.